# Scrollable fixed form to display on the left side

Tags: css, html

I would like to shown for example a mail icon on the left side of the screen like on the image below which would remain on a fixed position even when we scroll the page but when clicked a small form with an input field for a newsletter slides out.

How can I get that?

[image: Sticky icon form]

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple example. Fill out the form. Click "Full page". Preview for the snippet here bad works

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.page {
  width: 980 px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.form {
  top: 300px;
  left: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="form">
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn">My form</button>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: appreciate your time and help